# HTML - Lock default value in text area and user insert more info

Tags: html, forms, textfield

Im not sure on how to explain this but, what I want to know is there if there is any way to "lock" just one part of an text area in a html form. Example:

```
<input name="example" type="text" id="example" valeu="__this part cant be modified__, and here user insert aditional info" />
```

And then I get this field value as like: "**this part cant be modified** + what user typed"

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, your best bet would probably to just append your default value to their input upon submission.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn’t, not for `input` elements, not for `textarea` elements.

You can however create an impression of such behavior, e.g. having some text and an `input` element on the same line and setting their style as similar as possible (setting all text, background, and border properties). Of course, the form data would still consist of the `input` value. And prepending the fixed text to it in client-side JavaScript would be possible but normally pointless, since it would be inherently unreliable and since you can simply make the form handler behave as if it got that string (i.e., make it have it as built-in data).